# ViewController with TalbeView and CollectionView tabs like Google+ in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to understand how to build something like this (google plus profile page):

[image]

Seems that there is a header (like tableheaderview) and, when the user tap on Foto, Post or Info the bottom change to UiTableView, UiCollectionView.

How can i realize this? With ContainerView?

Comment: just add UiCollectionView to UiTableViewCell. That's it

Comment: it's that simple? Occam was right!

Comment: yes, that's very easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple (thanks to [Natarajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3420996/natarajan)):

> just add UiCollectionView to UiTableViewCell. That's it